# Centre of pressure in an oil tank (single variable calculus, drawing included)

Tags: calculus

**Problem:**

An oil tank in the shape of a straight circular cylinder with radius $R$ has a horizontal axis and is filled to half with oil with the density $\rho$.

Determine the total force of the pressure on one of the short sides of the tank. Also determine the center of pressure (i.e. the point for the combined total force from the pressure)

**Attempted solution:**

Here is an image of the situation (looking from the short side of the tank):

[image]

The pressure at the point $(x, y)$ at right angle to the short side of the tank (the one we are looking at in the drawing) is $\rho g y$. This is the standard formula for pressure at some height.

Consider a horizontal section with the area $dA$ at depth $y$. The force on it is:

$$dF = \rho g y dA = \rho g y \cdot 2\sqrt{R^2-y^2} dy$$

This is because force is pressure times area.

Here I will assume that the y-coordinate of the center of pressure needs to be calculated and that I can just assume, due to symmetry, that the x-coordinate is on the axis of symmetry.

This leads to the following formula where $P_{total}$ is total pressure:

$$P_{total} \cdot y_{center~of~pressure} = \int ydF$$

or equivalently,

$$y_{center~of~pressure} = \frac{1}{P_{total}}\int ydF = \frac{1}{\rho g y} \int \rho g y^2 \cdot 2\sqrt{R^2 -y ^2} = \frac{2}{y} \int y^2 \sqrt{R^2 -y ^2}$$

(presumably, the ingration should be from $0$ to $y$)

However, this integral seems to difficult for the difficulty level of the problem. Even Wolfram Alpha times out.

The expected answer is:

Total force of the pressure:

$$\frac{2\rho gR^3}{3}$$

Centre of pressure is on the symmetry axis at a distance of:

$$\frac{3\pi R}{16}$$

below the surface of the liquid.

I must have made some mistake setting up the scenario. What are some productive ways to finish this question off?

**Bountry:**

I am looking for a (1) pedagogic explanation of how to get from the scenario to an integral expression for each of the metrics in the question and what integral expressions it would be and (2) a single variable calculus solution that does not involve multivariable calculus or merely elementary geometry. I may settle for (1) alone if it is thorough enough.

(Current answers by e. g. TeM are not sufficient for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies in your definition of the center of pressure. If you compare the dimensions of both sides of your equation, you would immediately see that it doesn't work out. Pressure times distance is not equivalent to force times distance. Also, note that the total pressure would not be $\rho g y$ but the integration of the differential pressure $dP = \rho g dy$. It doesn't make sense to have the variable $y$ inside and outside the integral if you are expecting an answer that isn't a variable.

This is the equation you want:

$$ F_\text{total} \cdot y_\text{center of pressure} = \int y dF$$

Your equation for $dF$ is correct. You may then acquire the total force from the integral of $dF$ as below. I recommend u-substitution to solve this integral.

$$F_\text{total} = \int dF = 2 \rho g \int_{0}^{R} y \sqrt{R^2 - y^2} dy$$

You should acquire the expected answer for the total force from the pressure. Now you need to evaluate the following integral for the center of pressure. I recommend trig substitution to solve this integral.

$$y_\text{center of pressure} = \frac{1}{F_\text{total}} \int ydF = \frac{2 \rho g}{\frac{2 \rho g R^3}{3}}\int_{0}^{R} y^2 \sqrt{R^2 - y^2}dy = \frac{3}{R^3}\int_{0}^{R} y^2 \sqrt{R^2 - y^2}dy$$

You should once again arrive at the expected answer. Also, if you run into WolframAlpha issues involving standard computation time, it may be because you have $R$ plugged into the integral. Try substituting in values for $R$ and compare the results with the expected answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I now understand how to get from the set up to the integrals and from there it was easy. The last integral was solvable in the definite form and then I did the calculations on my own. The results are what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since the *pressure distribution* is the following:

[image]

it should not be difficult to understand that the *integration domain* is:

$$
\Omega := \left\{ (x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 
-R \le x \le R, \; 
0 \le y \le \sqrt{R^2-x^2}, \; 
0 \le z \le \gamma\,y \right\}
$$

from which:

$$
\begin{aligned}
||\Omega|| 
& := \iiint\limits_{\Omega} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z \\
& = \int_{-R}^R \text{d}x \int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \text{d}y \int_0^{\gamma\,y} \text{d}z \\
& = \int_{-R}^R \text{d}x \int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \gamma\,y\,\text{d}y \\
& = \int_{-R}^R \frac{\gamma}{2}\left(R^2-x^2\right)\text{d}x \\
& = \frac{2}{3}\,\gamma\,R^3 \;;
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{y} 
& := \frac{1}{||\Omega||}\iiint\limits_{\Omega} y\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z \\
& = \frac{3}{2\,\gamma\,R^3} \int_{-R}^R \text{d}x \int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} y\,\text{d}y \int_0^{\gamma\,y} \text{d}z \\
& = \frac{3}{2\,\gamma\,R^3} \int_{-R}^R \text{d}x \int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \gamma\,y^2\,\text{d}y \\
& = \frac{3}{2\,\gamma\,R^3} \int_{-R}^R \frac{\gamma}{3}\,\sqrt{\left(R^2-x^2\right)^3}\,\text{d}x \\
& = \frac{1}{2\,R^3} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\left(R^2-R^2\,\sin^2\theta\right)^3}\,R\,\cos\theta\,\text{d}\theta \\
& = \frac{R}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^4\theta\,\text{d}\theta \\
& = \frac{R}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{3 + 4\,\cos(2\,\theta) + \cos(4\,\theta)}{8}\,\text{d}\theta \\
& = \frac{3}{16}\,\pi\,R \;;
\end{aligned}
$$

which correspond respectively to the *hydrostatic force* to which the semicircular surface is subject and the vertical position of the *center of pressure*.

In any case, the integral calculation isn't indispensable, it's enough to know the *geometry of areas*:

- $F = \gamma\,y_G \cdot A = \gamma\,\frac{4\,R}{3\,\pi} \cdot \frac{\pi\,R^2}{2} = \frac{2}{3}\,\gamma\,R^3$;
- $y_C = \frac{J_O}{A\,yG} = \frac{\pi\,R^4/8}{2\,R^3/3} = \frac{3}{16}\,\pi\,R$;

where the significant geometric quantities $y_G,\,A,\,J_O$ refer to the semicircular surface in question.

Comment: Your solution is surely very nice and high quality, but far beyond my knowledge or the requested scope of the question (single variable calculus label is in the title). I am sure it will be very helpful for others who come across your answer in their searches. My biggest trouble is going from the image to setting up a single variable integral expression for the two requested metrics.